# Overwrite css in nested elements

Tags: css

I have a nested html structure with divs inside divs (creating rows inside rows). I need to allow user to set div (row) css (add css class).
I'm struggling to find a solution when css specificity is the same.
For example I want to create four level nested rows and have first row with red border, second and third with blue and fourth with red. With below markup and css fourth row has blue border instead of red because css specificity is the same and last class is applied.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        .main {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
        }

            .main .row {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border: 1px solid #808080;
            }

                .main .row [class*="span"] {
                    display: block;
                    min-height: 30px;
                    margin-top: 5px;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                }

            .main .red .bp1 {
                border: 2px solid red;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }


            .main .blue .bp1 {
                border: 2px solid blue;
                margin-left: 20px;
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="row red">
            <div class="span bp1">
                <div class="row blue">
                    <div class="span bp1">
                        <div class="row blue">
                            <div class="span bp1">
                                <div class="row red">
                                    <div class="span bp1"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row blue">
            <div class="span bp1">
                <div class="row red">
                    <div class="span bp1">
                        <div class="row blue">
                            <div class="span bp1">
                                <div class="row red">
                                    <div class="span bp1"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In second nested divs I want to get blue / red / blue / red rows, unfortunately all are blue because that's the last style class.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: @editor are you crazy?  You don't restructure OP's code when OP is asking a question about that code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to the end of any property value that you want to override. e.g., `width: 100% !important;`

Comment: adding `!important` is not real solution, it is a dirty 'hack' that should only be used when all else fails!

Answer (score 0):

If you use direct child selector: > , you should get something that works.

```
.main {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
        }

            .main .row {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border: 1px solid #808080;
            }

                .main .row [class*="span"] {
                    display: block;
                    min-height: 30px;
                    margin-top: 5px;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                }

            .main .red > .bp1 {
                border: 2px solid red;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }


            .main .blue > .bp1 {
                border: 2px solid blue;
                margin-left: 20px;
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
```